# XAML Binding to Element in a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am adding an `EntityControl` to an `EdgeControl`. `EdgeControl` contains an element named `PART_edgePath`. I am trying to bind to this element from within `EntityControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.Graph.EntityControl" ... >

<Ellipse Width="15" Height="15"  Fill="Blue">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform X="-7.5" Y="-7.5" />
            <!-- use radius to shift circle to path -->
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
                                            Source="X" Duration="{Binding Path=Duration}"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform"
                                            PathGeometry="{Binding ElementName=PART_edgePath, Path=Data, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource GeometryToPathGeometry}}"/>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
                                            Source="Y" Duration="{Binding Path=Duration}"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform"
                                            PathGeometry="{Binding ElementName=PART_edgePath, Path=Data, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource GeometryToPathGeometry}}"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>

</UserControl>
```

The source element is located in a ContentTemplate in a Style. This worked very well previously when I had the `EntityControl` inside the Style as well:

```
<ResourceDictionary ... >

<!-- EDGE CONTROL -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type gxl:EdgeControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type gxl:EdgeControl}">
                <Canvas x:Name="EdgeCanvas">
                    <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                      StrokeThickness="2" MinWidth="1" MinHeight="1"
                      ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"
                        x:Name="PART_edgePath"/>
                    <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                      StrokeThickness="2" MinWidth="1" MinHeight="1" 
                        x:Name="PART_edgeArrowPath"/>


                    <!-- HERE the EntityControl was part of the style -->
                    <!--<Ellipse ... />-->

                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I create the `EntityControl` in the code programmatically:

```
EntityControl entity = new EntityControl();
Canvas canvas = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(edgeControl, 0) as Canvas;
canvas.Children.Add(entity);
entity.InitializeComponent();
entity.UpdateLayout();
```

Unfortunately the `DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry` of `EntityControl` is empty.
I tried many things to make it work but failed. Some clarification about why this doesn't work and how I could/should make it work would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You should really write a shorted version of your code and explain the problem. i didn't understand what the problem was because your question is soooooooooooooo..... long .
why the hell would any one need to see your triggers for instance..
Please edit this question.

Comment: done, removed what I figured to be rather unnecessary.

Comment: excellent , that's a good question i need to try it out to give you a concrete answer .

In general i would think that only sibling elements in the same visual tree could be reffered to by ElementName 

what you could do is expose a Path DepedencyProperty in your EntityControl , Bind between it and your path element and than in your entity control bind RelativeSource Self between the animation and the DP.